# Calling a function with a same name as a parent class function pointer

Tags: c++, function, function-pointers

I'm trying to get a variety of `Nodes` to run a defined `execute` function that is passed in to a constructor and stored (and called) from a function pointer variable.

```
class Node{
    std::string(*execute)();
};

Node::Node(std::string(*funcPointer)()){
    execute = funcPointer;
}
```

I also have several derived classes that all also have an `execute` funcion

```
class redNode : public Node{
    std::string execute();
};

std::string redNode::execute(){
    return "I'm red";
}

class blueNode : public Node{
    std::string execute();
};

std::string blueNode::execute(){
    return "I'm red";
}
```

Then, I want to call all of the Node's `execute` functions.

```
std::string myFunc(){
     return "my Func";
}

Node mynode = new Node(&myFunc);
//other instantiations here...

myRedNode.execute();
myBlueNode.execute();
myNode.execute();
```

However, trying to call `.execute()` of `myRedNode` or `myBlueNode` doesn't work because the `execute` variable that's a part of the parent class was never set and it seems to be calling that. Trying to then set the `execute` variable

```
myBlueNode.execute = &BlueNode::execute;
```

gives a `error C2659: '=' function as left operand`, even when I rename the function I'm setting the variable to.

How do I solve this problem? How do correctly call function with a same name as a parent class function pointer?

Comment: why aren't you using a virtual `execute()` function that follows the function pointer? Then child class ctors can just be `RedNode() : Node(&red_execute)`

Comment: Your description of the problem is not quite clear. Please post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Please write ctor declarations.

Answer (score 1):

`&BlueNode::execute` is not just a function pointer. It's a member function pointer. It can be used by this way:

```
std::string (BlueNode::*pf)();
pf = &BlueNode::execute;

BlueNode obj;
(obj.*pf)();
```

But this forces the function to be member of specific class, and I think you don't want it (If so, you would just use virtual function.)

I suggest use `std::function<>`.

```
class Node
{
    std::function<std::string()> execute;
public:
    Node(std::function<std::string()> _execute)
        : execute(std::move(_execute))
    {
    }
};
```

You can use normal functions, member functions, functors and lambda.

```
std::string f1() { return "f1"; }
struct T { std::string f2() { return "f2"; } };
struct F { std::string operator ()() const { return "f3"; } };

T obj;
Node n1 { f1 };
Node n2 { std::bind(&T::f2, &obj) };
Node n3 { F() };
Node n4 { []() { return std::string("f4"); } };
```

[(live example)](http://ideone.com/pDgkuF)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, `&BlueNode::execute` isn't a function pointer, it's a pointer to member function. To you `&BlueNode::execute` you also need a class pointer to use it on. For instance:

```
std::string (BlueNode::*memberFunctionPointer)();
memberFunctionPointer = &BlueNode::execute;

BlueNode blueNode;
(blueNode.*memberFunctionPointer)();
```

To do what you want(set a variable in the parent to call an arbitrary function), you would need to use `std::function` and `std::bind` to collect an instance and member function pointer, which @ikh has explained, or if that's not what you really want to do, you can also change the pointer in the parent to be a member function pointer and call it on the instance of the child, or you could use virtual functions to do that automatically.

Now the second problem that you are having, why is it giving `error C2659: '=' function as left operand` when you try to do `myBlueNode.execute = &BlueNode::execute;` is because the derived class methods `execute` are hiding the parent variable `execute`. To access the hidden variable you need to access the object as the parent type by casting it. Here is an example, just using a stand alone function:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class Base
{
    public:
    Base(std::string (*funcPointer)()) { execute = funcPointer; }

    std::string (*execute)();
};

std::string StandaloneExecute()
{
    return std::string("StandaloneExecute");
}

class Derived: public Base
{
    public:
    Derived() : Base(StandaloneExecute) {}

    std::string execute() //this hides the parent execute
    {
        return std::string("Derived::Execute");
    }
};


int main() {
    Derived d;
    std::cout << d.execute() << std::endl; //this will print Derived::Execute
    std::cout << static_cast<Base>(d).execute() << std::endl; //this will print StandaloneExecute
    return 0;
}
```

[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/OOoGN6)